# Prevent Row from unnecessary recomposition in Jetpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have three Rows in Column.

Then I change focus all three rows try to recompose.

Then I click on second Row, it try to set focus on the last.

How to recompose only row, there focus is?

```
@Composable
fun CreateRow(focusRequester: FocusRequester){
  Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable(focusRequester.requestFocus())){
   BasicTextField(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester))
  }
}

@Composable
fun AppStart(){
  val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
  CreateRow(focusRequester = focusRequester)
  CreateRow(focusRequester = focusRequester)
  CreateRow(focusRequester = focusRequester)
}
```

Comment: Not sure where you see recompositions, but when I fixed this code to compile, as it is not compiling like this, it had minimal recompositions inside Row where my focus is and where I type text